# Why is $|x|$ not differentiable at $x=0$?

Tags: limits, derivatives

The definition of a derivative is the slope of a function tangent to a point. It is also defined as $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
If we apply this to $f(x)= |x|$, we get that it is $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{|h|}{h}$, which is undefined. However, if we look at the graph of $|x|$, we see that there can exist a tangent line at x=0, with slope 0. So why is the derivative undefined instead of 0?

Comment: @MathN00b: What is your definition of a "tangent line"? :)

Comment: A line that touches a function at exactly 1 point in the neighborhood of the function.

Comment: then there are infinitely many tangents for x=0

Comment: This is not the definition of a tangent line.

Comment: @MathN00b: That's not the usual definition. :) Here's why it's not a "good" definition: If your graph were a horizontal line, say $y = 0$, then _every non-horizontal line_ would be "tangent" by the "touches at one point" criterion. If instead your curve were a parabola, say $y = x^{2}$, then _every line whatsoever_ would be tangent according to "touches at one point (in a neighborhood)".

Comment: @MathN00b: By your definition, any line that *crosses* a graph would also be considered tangent to it. Informally, a tangent line at a point is **the** (that is, the *unique*) line that a graph looks like when you zoom-in really-really-REALLY closely on that point. If the graph doesn't look like a line up-close to a point, then it simply has no tangent there. The graph of $|x|$ doesn't look like a line at $x=0$; no matter how closely you zoom-in on $(0,0)$, the graph will look like a "V".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(x) = |x|$. For $x > 0$, the gradient is $1$, whereas for $x < 0$, the gradient is $-1$. At $x = 0$, you have infinitely many lines,  which are represented by the subgradient $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for clarifying

Comment: Replace "infinitely many tangent lines" by "no tangent line".

Comment: @Did, I've wanted to emphasize the idea of subgradient. I have delete the term "tangent".

Comment: @Did Sir, please explain why not to use "Infinitely many tangent lines"? If not Infinitely many then how many? Can't saying that, there is no tangent line implies there is No right hand and No left hand derivative at that point? (But clearly i think both right hand derivative and left hand derivative exists at $x=0$ for f(x)=|x|$) elaborate please.

Answer (score 2):

The following expressions could all be "tangent" lines of $|x|$ at $x=0$ if one were to use a naive definition of tangent:
\begin{align}
y_1(x) &= \frac12x\\
y_2(x) &= 0\\
y_3(x) &= -\frac13x
\end{align}
since they all have exactly the point $(0,0)$ in common with $|x|$. So the derivative of $|x|$ at $x=0$ should be $1/2$, $0$, and $-1/3$?

A tangent line only really makes sense as a limit of secant lines which you see by your limit does not make sense for $|x|$ at $x=0$.

By the way, the [weak derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative) of $|x|$ is actually the function you described, which is $-1$ when $x<0$, $0$ when $x=0$, and $1$ when $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=-x$ separately. Clearly the equation of the derivative has a discontinuity at $x=0$.

Comment: Yes, but why is it not defined to be $0$ at $x=0$? With the limit definition I see it does not exist, but not with the slope of tangent definition.

Comment: It is $0$ at $f(x)=0$. This doesn't solve the discontinuity problem. Why the downvote by the way?

Comment: I meant the derivative at $x=0$ And it is because it does not answer my question.

Comment: I think it does. The function in your question is not differentiable at $x=0$ because the derivative is not continuous at $x=0$, hence the derivative does not exist.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281601/why-is-the-derivative-of-fracxx-equal-to-emptyset-at-x-0

Comment: @MathN00b The tangent definition requires a **unique** tangent. Can you draw a unique tangent line at $x = 0 $?

Comment: "The function in your question is not differentiable at x=0 because the derivative is not continuous at x=0, hence the derivative does not exist." Ouch! The derivative function could have a jump and still exist at the location of the jump.

Comment: A jump discontinuity, I mean

Comment: In fact when you combine this with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29, it becomes a correct anwswer: derivatives can have discontinuities, but not "jump" (or "simple") discontinuities.

Comment: Derivative at a point is a limit at a point. Limit at a point exists when $\lim_{x \to a{-}} = \lim_{x \to a^{+}}$. In this case $\lim_{x \to a{-}} \neq \lim_{x \to a^{+}}$, so the limit at this point doesn't exist, so the derivative at the point doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=|x|=\begin{cases}
x \text{ if } x>0\\
0 \text{ if } x=0\\
-x \text{ if } x<0
\end{cases}$

$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{|x|}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^-}=\frac{-x}{x}=-1$ but similarly if we check the right hand limit, we see that we get $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{|x|}{x}=1$, and since $1\neq -1$, we don't have have a derivative at the point $x=0$.

Comment: Yes, but why is it not defined to be $0$ at $x=0$? With the limit definition I see it does not exist, but not with the slope of tangent definition.

Comment: You might want to see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166474/why-is-a-function-at-sharp-point-not-differentiable

Answer (score 1):

What does "tangent line" mean? Intuitively, it means a line that provides a *good linear approximation* to the function near that point. More precisely, suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function, $L: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function whose graph is a line, and $p \in \mathbb{R}$ is a point. We say "$L$ is tangent to $f$ at $p$" if and only if, as $x \to p$, we have
$$
f(x) = L(x) + o(x - p).
$$
In other words, the difference between $f(x)$ and $L(x)$ shrinks *faster than linearly* as $x$ approaches $p$. (One can check that this is equivalent to the usual definition of derivative; however, this formulation also generalizes more readily to higher dimensions.)

The reason $f(x) = \lvert x \rvert$ has no tangent line at $x = 0$ is that there is no such "good linear approximation". For example, consider the line $L(x) = 0$ with slope zero: we have $f(x) - L(x) = \lvert x \rvert$, which shrinks *linearly* as $x$ approaches zero. Similarly, if we chose $L(x) = -x$, then we'd have $f(x) - L(x) = \lvert x \rvert + x$, which is equal to $2x$, a linear function, for $x > 0$.

Answer (score -5):

If you draw the graph of the equation, you will get a v-shaped configuration with the vertex located at x=0, y=0.

If you try to put a tangent at that vertex point, you will see that the line can take on one of innumerable slopes and still be "touching at one point". It's undefined.

Comment: "If you try to put a tangent at that vertex point, you will see that the line can take on one of innumerable slopes and still be "touching at one point"" That's true also for $f(x) = x^3$ at $x = 0$.  So your argument is unconvincing.

Comment: No Peter. You are wrong. dy/dx would be 3x^2. At x=0 there is one and only one tangent. That would be a tangent with slope = 0

Comment: First, please do not call me "Peter".  Second: the point of my comment is that the function I gave has a tangent line but satisfies the property that I quoted: namely, there is more than one line passing through the point $(0,0)$ which intersects the curve at only one point.  Therefore this "touching at one point" business cannot be the definition of the tangent line.  For another kind of counterexample, consider $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$.

Comment: Well, this OP seems to be having trouble seeing the difference between physical reality and pure mathematics. I think the OP is trying to reconcile a pure math concept with physical reality.